# setting setState in react hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have two buttons `create signature` and `Create delivery` in `PageOne.tsx` , at the moment when state is `InDelivery` then both are visible.

My point is how to hide `Create delivery` button in the beginning, but when user clicks `create signature` button which is in `PageTwo` and inside that page user clicks `Submit` button which takes user back to this `PageOne.tsx`.

Then here only `Create delivery` button should be visible, would appreciate if somebody use my code and provide working example, (I'm new to react) my code:

```
import React, { ReactNode, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
export function PageOne(props: React.PropsWithChildren<OrderDetailsDto>) {

    const [deliveredd, setDeliveredd] = useState(false);

    const RedirectToSign = () => {
        setDeliveredd(true);

        history.push("/PageTwo/" + orderId);
    };

    const RedirectToDeliv = () => {
        history.push("/PageThree/" + orderId);
    };
    const SignatureButton = () => {
        if (initialRequest.type == ApiRequestStatus.Complete) {
            var state = initialRequest.responsePayload.order?.state as OrderState;

            if (state == OrderState.InDelivery || state == OrderState.Delivered) {
                return (
                    <div onClick={RedirectToSign} className="Button">
                        create signature
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
    };
    const UpdateButton = () => {
        if (state === OrderState.InDelivery) {
            return (
                <div onClick={RedirectToDeliv} className="Button">
                    Create delivery
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    console.log(deliveredd);
    return (
        <div className="orderDetails">

            {UpdateButton()}
            {SignatureButton()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

my PageTwo would be something like this :

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Form, Input } from "antd";


export function PageTwo(props: React.PropsWithChildren<CreateSignatureProps>) {


    const SendSignature = (values: Values) => {

        api.cargoApi
            .apiCargSignaturePost(request)
            .then((response) => history.push("/PageOne/" + orderId));
    }


    return (
        <Form onFinish={SendSignature}>
            <Form.Item>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                    {t("signature.create")}
                </Button>
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do. When you are redirecting from `PageTwo` to `PageOne`, pass a state which indicates which button to hide and which button to show in `PageOne`.

In `PageTwo`:

```js
history.push({
  pathname: "/PageOne/" + orderId,
  state: { hideCreateDelivery: true,  showCreateSignature: true}
})
```

In `PageOne`:

```
// to get the data from redirection
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

// Inside PageOne
const location = useLocation();

// replace this
return (
  <div className="orderDetails">
    {location.state && location.state.hideCreateDelivery ? null: UpdateButton()}
    {location.state && location.state.showCreateSignature 
      ? SignatureButton()
      : null}
   </div>
 );
```